# Springboot + ReactJS + Firebase's Realtime Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase-realtime-database

Back-end: Springboot
Front-end: ReactJS
CloudRepo: Firebase Realtime Database

1. I have a Springboot application that GETs data from the Firebase Realtime Database.
2. This data is then served via a GET request from reactJS.

I get the JSON object in reactJS as :

[image]

What I am trying to do is to map the firebase snapshot to a Java Collection. Here is What I have done so far:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseService.getFirebaseDatabase().getReference("/devices/device1");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DeviceData message = messageSnapshot.getValue(DeviceData.class);
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        Map<String, DeviceData> document = (Map<String, DeviceData>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        setUpdatedDocumentData(document);
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.out.print("-----Error-----:\n" + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

My POJO looks like this:

```
public class DeviceData {
    String sensor_1;
    String sensor_2;

    public DeviceData() {}

    public DeviceData(String sensor_1, String sensor_2) {
        this.sensor_1 = sensor_1;
        this.sensor_2 = sensor_2;
    }

    public String getSensor_1() {
        return sensor_1;
    }

    public void setSensor_1(String sensor_1) {
        this.sensor_1 = sensor_1;
    }

    public String getSensor_2() {
        return sensor_2;
    }

    public void setSensor_2(String sensor_2) {
        this.sensor_2 = sensor_2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DeviceData{" +
                "sensor_1='" + sensor_1 + '\'' +
                ", sensor_2='" + sensor_2 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am getting null in my sensor_1 and sensor_2 log. How can I map the above firebase structure to a collection?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. For the JSON: You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have edited the question Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under each `/devices/$device` node, you have two nested levels:

1. For the date
2. For the time.

Your code only has once loop over the children of the device node, so your `messageSnapshot` variable is actually a snapshot with all data for all timestamps for a specific date.

To handle your structure correctly, you need two nested loops:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseService.getFirebaseDatabase().getReference("/devices/device1");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot timeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DeviceData message = timeSnapshot.getValue(DeviceData.class);
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }

        Map<String, DeviceData> document = (Map<String, DeviceData>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        setUpdatedDocumentData(document);
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.out.print("-----Error-----:\n" + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

---

If you only care about the latest timestamp on the latest date, you can reduce the amount of data you read from the database by only getting the latest date:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseService.getFirebaseDatabase().getReference("/devices/device1");
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot timeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DeviceData message = timeSnapshot.getValue(DeviceData.class);
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }

        Map<String, DeviceData> document = (Map<String, DeviceData>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        setUpdatedDocumentData(document);
    }

    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.out.print("-----Error-----:\n" + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

You'll still have to read all timestamps for that date, but at least you're now only reading data for the most recent day.

Comment: Ok. So this works well. I can see and print out all the data I want now. Thanks.
But I am trying to create a collection of this data and the collection seems to always be empty. Any idea on how can I bucket this up into a single collection? I WANT TO POPULATE THIS DATA INTO A TABLE IN THE FRONT END.

Comment: You'll want to add all the sensor readings to a single list, and then create an adapter on that. That part is unrelated to Firebase though, so I'd recommend doing a search on something like https://www.google.com/search?q=creating+an+android+adapter+on+a+list+of+data

Comment: Frank van Puffelen The problem posted was resolved partially but I still am stuck with the for loops being running infinite times. Any reason why?

Comment: I don't see in the code you shared what is causing that, but it could happen **if** your `setUpdatedDocumentData` updates the data under `devices/device1`. If so, consider if you want to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: I have tried using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` but it still gets stuck in the loop.

Comment: In that case I either don't understand what the loop is, or where it comes from. I recommend opening a new question for that problem with the [minimal, complete/standalone code/data with which anyone can reproduce it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).